# Incorrect output for Permutation checker when using char array

Tags: java, string

I have the following code to return a boolean value indicating whether one string can be permutation of another. 
Assumption is that we are using an ASCII character set

When passing the following 2 strings, the output is still true
        System.out.println(checkPermutation("dog", "odf"));

What is missing?

```
public static boolean checkPermutation(String s1, String s2) {

    if(s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    char[] letters = new char[128];
    for(char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
        letters[c]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        int c = (int) s2.charAt(i);
        letters[c]--;
        if(letters[c] < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @NimitPatel: Java array elements (and class and instance fields) are always initialized to the appropriate zero which for `char` is `'\u0000'` see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea. You can use `indexOf` method of string to find if the characters are present in both strings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
    if (s1.indexOf(s2.charAt(i)) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be using an array of chars to store the counts of occurrences, rather than an array of integers (I'm guessing that `letters[c]` is never less than zero because a char cannot be less than zero).  I modified your code, and this should work:

```
public static boolean checkPermutation(String s1, String s2) {

    if(s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    int [] letters = new int[128];
    for(char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
        letters[c]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        int c = (int) s2.charAt(i);
        letters[c]--;
        if(letters[c] < 0) {
        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In particular (Java) `char` is unsigned, so decrementing `(char)0` gives the character `\uFFFF` which '<' converts to 65535 and that is not `< 0`